# Sarfari shortcut for showing "Tab Groups" in sidebar?

Tags: safari

If I'm viewing my bookmarks in the sidebar and want to show the tab groups in the sidebar instead, how do I do it with a shortcut key instead of clicking on the back arrow in the sidebar?

There doesn't seem to be an options for it in the "View" menu, either. Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: It really seems like there should be a way, but if there is, I can't find it. Seems like an oversight!